# Checking out a git branch while in a path that exists only in the initial branch

Tags: git

Can anyone help me make sense of this quirk I've found with git?

Here's how to reproduce this quirk:

```
$ mkdir git-test && cd git-test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git-test/.git/
$ echo hello > world
$ git add world
$ git commit -m'first commit'
[master (root-commit) 5f68103] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 world
```

Cool, all right so far; now let's branch off:

```
$ git checkout -b a_branch
$ mkdir a_dir
$ echo foo > a_dir/bar
$ git add a_dir/bar
$ git commit -m message
[a_branch (root-commit) 2fbef71] message
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a_dir/bar
```

OK, here comes the quirk!

```
$ cd a_dir
$ pwd
/tmp/git-test/a_dir
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ pwd
/tmp/git-test/a_dir
```

WTF!? this path DOES NOT EXIST in this branch!

```
$ ls
total 0
```

Even `ls` seems to work...

```
$ cd ..
$ ls
world
```

The directory `a_dir' has now magically disappeared!

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this has not much to do with git.

Your current working directory is being removed by some process (in this case the git branch switch). The same thing would happen if you `rmdir` the current working directory.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ rmdir ../test/
$ pwd
/tmp/test
$ ls /tmp/test
ls: /tmp/test: No such file or directory
```

You can see similar effect when deleting files that are open: They will disappear from the file system, but the program that opened them can still access them, and disk space will only be reclaimed after the program closes them. Note that this behaviour is completely different between UNIXy systems and Windows. Windows would not be let you delete them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the directory is locked because you are cd'd into it... So the change to branch master cannot remove the dir while it is in use...